# How do I change the value of a Django Model field via a template function based view in django

Tags: javascript, html, django, templates, django-models

I have a django function based view, inside it a I have a checklist of checkmarks and some text, when I tap one I want the database to update, how do I accomplish this?

Note that I don't have made any efforts yet to change the value and I hope someone here can help me with that!

```
@login_required
def detailStudyplanPage(request,pk):
  username = request.user
  tks = Task.objects.filter(studyplan__id=pk)
  object = get_object_or_404(Studyplan,pk=pk)
  return render(request, 'detailStudyplan.html',{'object':object, 'MyName': username, 'tasks': tks})

class Checker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    checked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="person_who_checks_checker")
    canview = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, blank=True, related_name="can_view_checker")


            <div>
              <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar bg-success" style="width:42%;"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-between text-small">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                  <i class="material-icons">playlist_add_check</i>
                  <span>3/7</span>
                </div>
                <span>Ska vara färdig {{task.deadline}}</span>
              </div>
            </div>    




                    {% for checker in Checkers %}

                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="form-group col">
                        <span class="checklist-reorder">
                          <i class="material-icons">reorder</i>
                        </span>
                        <form method="post" action="{% url checker_check checker.id %}"></form>
                        <input type="checkbox" 
                        {% if checker.checked == True %}
                        checked
                        {% endif %}
                        >
                        <style>
                        .checkerName {
                          margin-left: 10px
                        }
                        </style>
                        <h class='checkerName'>{{ checker.name }}</h>
                      </div>


                      <!--end of form group-->
                    </div>

                    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: So ontap I want Checker.checked = True/False

Answer (score 1):

You create two new views with URLs like: `/checker/{id}/check` and `/checker/{id}/uncheck` and based on the tap you do a POST to the correct URL.

The URL is linked up to a view that retrieves the check object, changes its boolean property and saves it.

In the view:

```
checker = Checker.objects.get(pk=pk)
checker.checked = True
checker.save()
```

Comment: ur a legend mate

Comment: I tried this @login_required
def changeCheckerState(request,pk):
    if request.method == "PUT":
        print (request.PUT)
    else:
        return redirect('/')

Comment: how do I proceed from here

Comment: See the updated code. Change the model  maybe print what it's doing.

Comment: thanks, how should I do In the template? Just aa link to the url?

Comment: If you don't want to use javascript you can use a `<form method="post" action="{% url checker_check checker.id %}">` Forms don't support PUT methods, but POST should work.

Comment: I tried it, check above, don't really know where to put it!